# Replacing first three digit of a number

Tags: r

How can I replace numbers `421455,421855,....,421766` with `424455,424855,...,424766` in a vector?

Comment: `n + 3000`? seems pretty simple

Comment: `x <- c("421455", "421855", "421766");
substr(x, 1, 3) <- "424";
x`

Comment: Using `stringr`, `str_replace(c("421455","421855", "421766", "423123"), "^...", "424")`

Answer (score 2):

Using `sub()` and regular expressions:

```
x <- c(421455, 421855, 421766)
x <- sub("\\d{3}", "424", x)
x <- as.numeric(x)
x
[1] 424455 424855 424766
```

`\\d{3}` matches the first three digits in a row.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x<-c(421455,421855,421766)
as.numeric(paste0(424,substr(x,4,nchar(x))))
[1] 424455 424855 424766
```

This works if you want always in the first three positions `424`.

Otherwise `x + 3000` from Stephen Henderson in the comment is the solution